# Database queries from non-ActiveRecord model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hstore

In building an applications with Rails 3.2 and Postgres hstore, I'm running into an issue with a non-ActiveRecord model (using ActiveAttr at the moment, but open to other options). In short, I need to query the database to retrieve the set of keys in the hstore. As far as I can tell, this is only possible via a direct, non-ActiveRecord::Query statement.

My current code looks like this:

```
def self.keys(query)
  # FIXME Need to determine how to sanitize input
  sql = "SELECT DISTINCT key FROM ( SELECT skeys(data) AS key from \"products\" ) AS keys"
  if(query && !query.empty?)
    sql += " WHERE lower(key) LIKE '%#{query.downcase}%'"
  end
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values(sql)
end
```

This works, but doesn't sanitize the input `query`. If I try to create an array instead and change the key line to `sql += " WHERE lower(key) LIKE ?"` I get this error in my logs:

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `squeeze' for #<Array:0x007fd9968704e8>
TypeError: wrong argument type Array (expected String): ["SELECT DISTINCT key FROM ( SELECT skeys(data) AS key from \"products\" ) AS keys WHERE lower(key) LIKE ?", "%o%"]
```

Is it possible to call the appropriate sanitization method externally, or at least perform the same logic in my model?